# Creating a Border on a GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

[image: GUI]

I created this graphical interface, and what is missing is the "PERSONAL INFORMATION" border. I know that `setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("PERSONAL INFORMATION))` creates a border but how would I located the title to the Top Left, and input the correct dimensions so that the line doesn't go under the buttons without using layout managers. Much appreciated.

Comment: The title is top/left by default and the border insets are calculated automatically by the components `getPreferred/Miniumum/MaximumSize` method...

Comment: *"..without using layout managers."*  That's where you lose me.  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: @AndrewThompson We are not allowed using any layout managers and we must layout each component manually by calculating location and size. I wish we were allowed, it would have made it much easier to do.

Comment: *"..without using layout managers."*  I could show you how to lay it out like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/u4DeK.png)..  Would that suit the requirement?

Comment: *"We are not allowed using any layout managers"*  That is so illogical, that if it were specified by a teacher, they should be flogged.  If specified by an employer, find a new job.  Even with a 'custom' layout manager, it is 'using a layout manager'.  By the time you have laid out the components to fit the font size, screen resolution etc., you will have enough logic to justify **putting that logic** into a layout manager!

Comment: @AndrewThompson I guess our Professor is trying to get us to understand the very basics of GUI

Answer (score 4):

  -

---

```
   import java.awt.*;
   import javax.swing.*;
   import javax.swing.border.*;

class BorderTest extends JFrame
 {
 public BorderTest()
 {
setTitle("Border Test");
setSize(450, 450);

JPanel content = (JPanel) getContentPane(); 
content.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,2));

JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setBorder(new BevelBorder (BevelBorder.RAISED));
p.add(new JLabel("RAISED BevelBorder"));
content.add(p);

p = new JPanel();
p.setBorder(new BevelBorder (BevelBorder.LOWERED));
p.add(new JLabel("LOWERED BevelBorder"));
content.add(p);

p = new JPanel();
p.setBorder(new LineBorder (Color.black, 5));
p.add(new JLabel("Black LineBorder, thickness = 5"));
content.add(p);

p = new JPanel();
p.setBorder(new EmptyBorder (10,10,10,10));
p.add(new JLabel("EmptyBorder with thickness of 10"));
content.add(p);

p = new JPanel();
p.setBorder(new EtchedBorder (EtchedBorder.RAISED));
p.add(new JLabel("RAISED EtchedBorder"));
content.add(p);

p = new JPanel();
p.setBorder(new EtchedBorder (EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
p.add(new JLabel("LOWERED EtchedBorder"));
content.add(p);

p = new JPanel();
p.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder (SoftBevelBorder.RAISED));
p.add(new JLabel("RAISED SoftBevelBorder"));
content.add(p);

p = new JPanel();
p.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder (SoftBevelBorder.LOWERED));
p.add(new JLabel("LOWERED SoftBevelBorder"));
content.add(p);

p = new JPanel();
p.setBorder(new MatteBorder (new ImageIcon("spiral.gif")));
p.add(new JLabel("MatteBorder"));
content.add(p);

p = new JPanel();
p.setBorder(new TitledBorder ( new MatteBorder (new ImageIcon("spiral.gif")), "Title String"));
p.add(new JLabel("TitledBorder using MatteBorder"));
content.add(p);

p = new JPanel();
p.setBorder(new TitledBorder (new LineBorder (Color.black, 5), "Title String"));
p.add(new JLabel("TitledBorder using LineBorder"));
content.add(p);

p = new JPanel();
p.setBorder(new TitledBorder (
  new EmptyBorder (10,10,10,10),
  "Title String"));
p.add(new JLabel("TitledBorder using EmptyBorder"));
content.add(p);

setVisible(true);
 }

public static void main(String args[])
{
new BorderTest();
}
}
```

1. This Demo example is shows all Type of border.i  think so it is
   helpfull for you.

---

[image]